# Can I copy a bitlocker encrypted VHD to a different computer

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I created a VHD container and encrypted it with bitlocker on Windows 10.  I'm switching computers, so I copied the `.vhdx` file to my new system and tried to mount it.  When I click the "unlock" button, I get this message

> **BitLocker**
>
> BitLocker can't access this drive because of a problem with the PC or the drive itself.
>
> Error code: 0x80070002

The container still works fine on the old computer.  Is there something special I need to do to copy it?

Comment: This entirely depends if you have a TPM on either computer.  If you don't then it is definitely possible.

Comment: @Ramhound What's a TPM and how do I check if I have one?

Comment: What does your research indicate?

Comment: @Ramhound I figured out (I think) what a TPM is and there is not one in either computer.  Is there something special I need to do when I copy the file?